# postgresql copy comand with date in filename

Tags: postgresql, date, psql, copy, postgresql-12

I have a query and want the output in a .csv file with today's date and time in the name (I am using PostgreSQL v12).

```
COPY 
(SELECT * FROM mytable)
TO 'C:\Users\me\mylocation\filename_date_time.csv' CSV HEADER
```

where date_time is `YYYY-MM-DD-h_m_s` (or similar)

I have seen some solutions to this using bash. For various reasons I am on a Windows machine with no bash.

I would like to do this using psql please.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but I wanted to share what I have puzzled out as I was trying to achieve similar results and only found answers saying it had to be done via an anonymous function, pl/pgsql or similar.  **This can absolutely be done via plain sql either in psql directly or via a script passed to psql using psql variables**. The one thing I cannot work out for you is the proper way to return a date from the OS as I do not have access to a Windows machine. On Linux at least, using a command enclosed in back quotes (`) will embed the results of the command run from the OS in the psql variable as shown below; perhaps there is an equivalent call in Windows that can be substituted and then the rest should work fine using the psql variable for the output path and filename.

```
\set filename /tmp/DBSizes_as_of_`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`.csv

COPY (
       select datname
             ,pg_database_size(datname) as database_size
             ,pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as database_size_pretty
             ,now() as when
         from pg_database
     )
  TO :'filename'
WITH (
       FORMAT         csv
      ,OIDS           FALSE
      ,DELIMITER      ','
      ,HEADER         TRUE
      ,QUOTE          '"'
      ,ESCAPE         '"'
      ,ENCODING       'UTF8'
    )
;
```

Results shown from Linux command line are as follows:

```
# ls -la DBSizes*.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 postgres postgres 332 Aug 10 17:19 DBSizes_as_of_2022-08-10_17:10:00.csv

# cat DBSizes*.csv
datname,database_size,database_size_pretty,when
postgres,8066535,7877 kB,2022-08-10 17:10:00.697735+00
template_gis,15652327,15 MB,2022-08-10 17:10:00.697735+00
template1,8926695,8717 kB,2022-08-10 17:10:00.697735+00
template0,8058343,7869 kB,2022-08-10 17:10:00.697735+00
redacted,652026762727,607 GB,2022-08-10 17:10:00.697735+00
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamic SQL, for example with a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   datestr text := to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24_MI_SS');
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'COPY '
              '(SELECT * FROM mytable) '
              'TO %L CSV HEADER',
              'C:\Users\me\mylocation\' || datestr || '.csv'
           );
END;$$;
```